# How to send text file to textarea in selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I want to send the content of a text file to textArea of a webpage and my first code was to read the textFile into a String and then send it to the textArea But the problem is that this method takes a lot of time specially if the file is big

Is there is another efficient way to do that? I thought of copy the file cntrl+A cntrl+C cntrl+V but how to do that ?
and another idea is to drag and drop the text file into the text area but this didn't work with me

Comment: provide html source code please

Comment: for example this page https://atcoder.jp/contests/arc125/tasks/arc125_f and the text area at the end of it . But I think you will need to sign in first to see that text area

Comment: The text area accepts text only but why are doing drag and drop?

Comment: @NandanA There is an option on this web page to toggle editor and once I toggle it I will be apple to drag and drop the text file in it and the text will be loaded automatically in it within a second. sorry I forgot to mention that

Comment: @NandanA How to drag and drop text file in selenium Java I tried several methods(hacks) but non of them worked with me

Comment: @Omar_Hafez does below solution working for you?

Comment: @NandanA Unfortunately no it gives me `nullpointerexception` at the line `readProperties.getProperty("Data").trim();`  I think there is not Property "Data". Can you provide any source for this solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I come up with a **fast** solution to copy the content of text file regardless of the size of the file. The idea is to `get` the text file in WebDriver and then copy the content of the page using Selenium as follow:

```
driver.get("file://" + "The local path of my text file");
String content = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/pre")).getText();
```

This method is fast and takes lower than one second to read the content of the text file

Answer (score 0):

**Properties file**:

```
Data=The data which I want to send
```

**Load the properties file**:

```
public static Properties readProperties = new Properties();
public static void loadPropertiesFile() {
    File propertiesFile = new File(location of properties file);
    try {
        FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(propertiesFile);
        readProperties.load(fileInput);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error in loading the Properties file" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

**Read the properties file and get the data**:

```
String inputData = readProperties.getProperty("Data").trim();
System.out.println(inputData);
```

**Send the data**:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("element of text area")).sendKeys("inputData");
```