# How to wait till some value to be present on HTML tag?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I can use `Thread.sleep();` but my boss doesn't want me to do that so I used `explicit wait`

```
webDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xPath("")));
```

but it is not working as well because the `xpath` is not present as  the data(Text) that appears in sometime.

Comment: What XML library do you use? Die XML libraries from JDK are not thread-safe. There is no way to have something "second later" there...

Comment: actually it is a website on which there is a field and i need to get the text in it. for example. Unit: "Abc".  I'm giving the xpath for field "Abc" and applying get text function. but the moment the page loads, for first second it only shows the Unit field and text appears in some time eg (Unit: ) after a second (Unit: Abc) now there can be a situation where the Unit field is empty so the element is there when selenium checks for it. but it is empty and it gets the text as empty. I want a way where it waits for the text to appear in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If you know what text will be presented then you can use `textToBePresentInElementLocated` method. Let's see below example,

**HTML#1**:

```
  <input class="google"> Text </input>
```

**Wait till text presents** if you know the expected text

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@class='google']"), "Text"));
```

- If that value (abc) resides in an attribute then you can use below approach.

**HTML#2**:

```
  <input class="google" value="Text" >
```

**Wait till attribute** have some value

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='google']"));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.attributeToBeNotEmpty(element, "value"));
```

**How to read properties file?**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/69236087/7731623

**Dynamic xPath**:

```
/** Code to read properties file **/

String inputData = readProperties.getProperty("Data").trim();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='"+inputData+"']"));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.attributeToBeNotEmpty(element, "value"));
```

Comment: Thanks, but the value in the xpath, I can't hard code it because I'm getting it from .properties file. In other words I will have to give a variable in it, so in that case what should i do?

Comment: Read properties file and get the value them and pass it to `xPath`. Read this answer to read data from properties file https://stackoverflow.com/a/69236087/7731623

Comment: Can you please upvote if it helps?

Answer (score 0):

For that kind of situation apply `Explicit wait` such that the `attribute` of the tag is updated with some value.

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("xpath/tag[contains(@Unit,'Abc')]")));
```

You can also refer [This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69267561/16452840)